# is there any method to find perticular div from class in selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/earth/Downloads/Python/chromedriver_linux64 (2)/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://demo1.devmarketidiot.com/") # open url
driver.maximize_window() # maximize window`
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//[@id='__next']/div/div[1]/div/div/nav[1]/div/div/a[2]").click() # click on perticular element
html=driver.page_source

S= BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print("........Divs...........")
mydivs=S.findAll('div') # find all divs
print(len(mydivs))
divs1=S.find('div',class_="col-6")

for i in divs1:
    print("i:",i)
    print("len:",len(i))
```

Comment: Which particular `div` are you looking at? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: please format your code and better explain your problem

Comment: i want img or p in perticular not from all divs

Comment: did you try `findAll('img')` ?